# Embed CloudApp image in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've got a small image I'd like to embed in a Jupyter Notebook.

The image is hosted with [CloudApp](https://www.getcloudapp.com/) (it's a screenshot of some results).

I've done this so far in a cell, but it's just returning a broken image icon. Any hope?

```html
%%html
<img src="https://share.getcloudapp.com/xxx" width=60 height=60 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the app gives you an iframe to copy/paste, for embedding an image in Jupyter Notebook. Share > Embed > Copy in the app. The code cell seems to need %%html at the top to work.

Comment: So you got the iFrame to work? I'm in Google Collab and can't get it to work.

Comment: I got it to work with IPython.display.IFrame
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qMp4RvaJHW8reNYVgjLtR14YygmJnUlj?usp=sharing